# Tensor-flow installation issue

Tags: python, unix, matplotlib, tensorflow

**ipynb code:**

```
"import matplotlib as mpl\n",
    "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n",
    "import numpy as np\n",
    "import pandas as pd\n",
    "import tensorflow as tf\n",
    "\n",
    "from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # needed for project='3d'\n",
    "import helpers_02\n",
    "\n",
    "%matplotlib inline"
```

---

**Output:**

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import pandas as pd
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 
      7 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D # needed for project='3d'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Why does it say?
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

On trying to install using
C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-py2-none-any.whl

tensorflow-1.4.0-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This last install issue just happened to me. It seems as though the 1.4.0 version is not current. If you copy the URL from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow you can find a whl file for your python and os version. print(tf.VERSION) now gives 1.4.1